# magento sites all in a sudden showing blank frontend and backend

Tags: server-setup

we have 3 magento sites in a single server

www.site1.com , demo.site1.com, site2.com

our all 3 magento sites were working fine.

all in a sudden site1.com site's frontend and back end showed blank.

now demo.site1 site's frontend showing blank and admin panel working fine.

site2.com is working fine for both frontend and backend.

why these sites are showing blank in frontend and backend.

we are using amazon server. only 60 % space is used.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advnace.

Comment: please enable log using renaming local.xml.sample to local.xml at yourmagentodir/errors/

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply. I did, what next i have to do..?...

Comment: what is showing the error

Comment: by blank do you mean nothing is displayed or getting some kind of error ??

Comment: @Amit is error will display in frontend of site?

before frontend was not displaying , now it;s displaying but seems some menus and all relocated.....

Comment: @Dexter, before nothing was displaying. after renamed local.sample.xml to local.xml now site displaying.....

Comment: in admin panel, some menus are not displaying.....

Comment: there is no errors folderpresent in root of one site

Comment: eroor : The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Comment: @Amit, you can post as an answer, i will accept it.... rename local.xml.sample to local.xml....

Comment: yes sure...it will post

Comment: hi @amit ,can you please help me to integrate bludart shipping service API to magento site?

Comment: yes.sure. ..........

Comment: means what is the procedure, did you used any extension or did you integrated API itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to discuss with Baby in magento.The error not showing at system so  cannot  see the site.
I suggest to him renaming `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml` at `yourmagentodir/errors/` for print the error

Answer (score 0):

delete maintainance. flag file or rename it.... it's present tin root of the magento site : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102777/service-temporarily-unavailable-magento